# Finding Duplicate Objects in Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, duplicates

I'm having trouble trying to figure how to find duplicate numbers in the arrays. So, basically I have to figure whether there are duplicate ID numbers or not. And if there is, then the duplicate ID number will change to the max ID number plus one. But the thing is, in the array there are integers and strings because I'm getting it from a text file.

This is my test file which includes the last method where I need to code to find duplicates:

```
public class TestStudent
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    boolean bool = true;

    try
    {
        File file = new File("c:/temp/student2.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        Student studArray[] = new Student[100];
        int row = 0;

        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String lName = input.next();
            String fName = input.next();
            String state = input.next();
            int studID = input.nextInt();
            int satScore = input.nextInt();
            studArray[row] = new Student(studID, lName, fName, state, satScore);
            row++;
            if (row == 5)
            {
                studArray[row] = new Student();    
            }
        }
        studArray[row+1] = new Student(777, "Kim", "Brian", "VA", 1300);
        findDuplicates(studArray);
        read(studArray);


    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found!", "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
public static JTextArea read (Student studArray[])
{
    JTextArea outputOfArrays = new JTextArea();
    String text = "";
    text += "ID\tLast\tFirst\tState\tSAT score\n++++++\t"
            + "+++++++++\t+++++++++\t+++++++\t+++++++++++\n";
     for (int i = 0; i < studArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (studArray[i] != null)
        {
            text += studArray[i].StudentInfo() + "\n";
        }
    }
     outputOfArrays.append(text);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputOfArrays, "Data", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     return outputOfArrays;
}
**public static void findDuplicates(Student studArray[])
{   
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < studArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (max < studArray[i].getStudID() && studArray[i].getStudID() < 1000)
            {
                max = studArray[i].getStudID();
            }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < studArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < studArray.length; j++)
        {
            if(i != j && studArray[i].getStudID() == studArray[j].getStudID())
            {
                studArray[i].setStudID(max + 1);
                //max = studArray[i].getStudID() + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}**


}
```

This is what I wrote but I really feel like I did it all wrong...

This is my other java file I'm using with the test file:

```
public class Student
{
   private int studID;
   private String fName;
   private String lName;
   private String state;
   private int satScore;


public Student()
{
    studID = 0;
    lName = null;
    fName = null;
    state = null;
    satScore = 0;
}
public Student(int a, String b, String c, String d, int e)
{
    setStudID(a);
    setLName(b);
    setFName(c);
    setState(d);
    setSatScore(e);
}
public String StudentInfo()
{
    String output = studID + "\t" + lName + "\t" + fName + "\t" + state + "\t" +
            satScore;
    return output;
}

public int getStudID() {return studID;}
public String getFName() {return fName;}
public String getLName() {return lName;}
public String getState() {return state;}
public int getSatScore() {return satScore;}


public void setStudID(int a)
{
    studID = (a > 99) ? a : 0; 
    studID = (a < 1000) ? a : 0; 
}
public void setLName(String b)
{
    if(b.length() > 2 && b.length() < 11)
    {
        lName = b;
    }
    else if(b.length() > 10)
    {
        lName = b.substring(0, 10);
    }
    else if(b.length() < 2)
    {
        lName = null;
    }
}
public void setFName(String c)
{
    if(c.length() > 2 && c.length() < 11)
    {
        fName = c;
    }
    else if(c.length() > 10)
    {
        fName = c.substring(0, 10);
    }
    else if(c.length() < 2)
    {
        fName = null;
    }
}
public void setState(String d)
{
    String abbrState[] = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", 
        "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA",
        "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC",
        "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RO", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", 
        "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"};
    for(int i = 0; i < abbrState.length; i++)
    {
        if(d.equals(abbrState[i]))
        {
            state = d;
        }
    }
}
public void setSatScore(int e)
{
    satScore = (e > 400) ? e : 0;
    satScore = (e < 1600) ? e : 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Just two clarifications:<br/>
1. In case of string do you want to ignore them or just leave them as it is.<br/>
2. Suppose there are duplicates and one such duplicate id is 2 and it comes at 3, 6, 8 position. Max id is 50 so at position 3, everything cool but at 6 and 8, will it become 51?

Comment: There are no "strings" among the ID values. Input uses `input.nextInt()` and this either returns an integer from a digit sequence on the text file or it throws an exception.

Comment: @Tarun I want to leave the string as it is, for example the output of one of the arrays would be 123, Johnson, David, 1234. "123" is the studID. If another array has the same "123" studID and the max ID is "200" then the duplicate studID would change to "201".

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this method (and setSatScore as well):

```
public void setStudID(int a){
    studID = (a <= 99) ? 0 : (a >= 1000) ? 0 : a; 
}
```

And this is the improved method:

```
public static void findDuplicates(Student studArray[]){   
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < studArray.length; i++){
        if (max < studArray[i].getStudID() ){
            max = studArray[i].getStudID();
        }
    }
    Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < studArray.length; i++){
        int id = studArray[i].getStudID();
        if( used.contains( id ) ){
            studArray[i].setStudID(++max);   
        } else {
            used.add( id );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that an ID set to 0 due to a value out of range isn't changed.

Comment: I seem to get an error on the if(max < studArray[i].getStudUD()) part

Comment: If your input loop doesn't read values for all 100 students you will be in trouble. Object arrays are fickle, unless filled completely. Decide: throw away the array and use an ArrayList? Abort reading unless you can read 100? Keep track of the number of students on the input file and use that number rather than the array length?